# Vue.js fragment instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I seriously don't know, why the fragments is the problem.

```
<template>
   <div id="page">
   </div>

   <div class="some">
   </div>
</template>
```

> [Vue warn]: Attribute "id" is ignored on component "div"

Answer (score 10):

You need to wrap the contents of your template in another div. When it comes to render it, it needs the single root element to replace

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div id="page">
   </div>

   <div class="some">
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue v3 now supports multi-root templates. Your code should work out-of-the-box.

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html